# $H^1 \cap C^0$ boundary, smooth $H^1$ extension

Tags: sobolev-spaces, smoothness, extension

Assume we have a $u \in H^1(\Omega; \mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^0$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded open Set with smooth boundary. Also $u\vert_{\partial \Omega} \in H^1(\partial \Omega; \mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^0$. Now the question is, does there exist a $C^\infty$ extension $\tilde{u}$ to some $\tilde{\Omega} \supset \Omega$ such that $\tilde{u} \in H^1(\tilde{\Omega}; \mathbb{R}^n)$?

Note:
We always get a smooth extension, but if it would remain in $H^1$ is the hard part.

Comment: How can you have a $C^\infty$ extension if the original function is not $C^\infty$?

Comment: Extension, i mean that $u = \tilde{u}\vert_{\Omega}$, but $\tilde{u}\vert_{\tilde{\Omega} \setminus \overline{\Omega}}$ is smooth.